# Text alignment not proper

Tags: html, css, angularjs, text-alignment

I tried developing a mock up header for a website with branding (logo and brand name). I am using Angular.js for web page development. The logo is an URL of a image available online.
I am not able to proceed further with the web page development since i am stuck with this alignment issue. Please suggest the fix for this.

The screenshot of the header.
[image]

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="headerCtrl as header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img class="navbar-brand logo" src={{header.logoURL}}></img>
                <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">{{header.logoText}}</a>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </nav>

    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
body{
    top: 0px;
}
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.logo{
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The JS file

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller("headerCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log("Ctrl");
    this.logoURL = "http://sugartin.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/logo.png";
    this.logoText = "BrandName";
    this.slogan = " Roll out.";
}
])
```

Comment: remove custom css and it will work

Comment: Yes without Bootstrap css it works fine. But how do make use of css provided by bootstrap and fix the issue also.

Comment: use margin-top:10px in logo class

Comment: 10px i gave as example , but you can adjust or provide required value

Comment: .logo  's height is 100px; and you want your logo in center. and you have only margin problem.   Am i right ?

Comment: Add this `class="img-responsive"` in your img .. and check

Comment: why are you using `top: 0px;` for a static element?

Answer (score 0):

First make change in your css

```
.logo{
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height : 100px;
}
a.navbar-brand.logo.brandName{
        margin-left :0;
}
```

After that add .brandName class in the line.

```
<a class="navbar-brand logo brandName" href="#">{{header.logoText}}</a>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Custom CSS ( `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css"></link>`) and run. Only Use Bootstrap css. check this Demo: http://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/aZpVKN